# node.js + express + socket.io + codeigniter

Tags: node.js, codeigniter, sockets, express

I am unable to establish the connection between codeigniter and node.js using socket.io. I tried lots of things but I can't figure out a way to do this since I am somewhat new to node.js and totally new to socket.io.

Basically what want to do is update my codeigniter view using node.js in real time. so I use socket.io.

Here is how things looks like.

Folder structure

```
htdocs/myproject //codeigniter application
>application
--controller
***abcCon.php
--view
***abc.php
>flight //node application with express
--bin
***www
--routes
***index.js
---app.js
```

**In here :** 
codeigniter app seperatly works fine. *localhost/mydomain/flight_status/arrival_status* gives the expected view.
Node.js app seperatly works fine.
*localhost:3000/arrival_status* gives the expected json.

So how do I connect these two using socket.io? I went through lots of tutorials and non of them teach how to make through express installation.

Comment: You would make a view file and load in the socket.io JS files, and then connect to the Socket server?

Comment: Yesterday I was able to do that in view. Now the socket connection is established. but I can pass the connection to express router. There only my logic happens. Currently the connection is in bin/www file only.